# filter row by the content of a given column

Tags: jquery

the html:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="depCode">9</td>
    <td>ira furor brevis est!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here is my script:

```
    $("#repDepartement").keyup(function() {            
        var data = this.value;
        var rows = $("#representants").find("tr");
        if (data == '') {
            rows.show();
        } else {
            rows.hide();
            rows.filter(":contains('" + data + "')").show();
            //rows.filter(".depCode:contains('" + data + "')").show();
        }
    });
```

it works fine for filtering on the whole row content. But now I want to filter only in the content of the column having the depCode class.

I just can't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) can also filter using a function which you can use to get the content inside the elements that pass the selector `.depCode`

Note that the [`:contains` pseudo class selector](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/#article-header-id-9) is deprecated in CSS even though it still works in jQuery

```js
$("input").keyup(function() {
  var data = this.value;
  var rows = $("table").find("tr");
  if (data == '') {
    rows.show();
  } else {
    rows.hide();
    rows.filter(function () {
      return $(this).find('.depCode').text().indexOf(data) > -1
      // case insensitive solution
      // var columnValue = $(this).find('.depCode').text().toLowerCase()
      // var other = data.toLowerCase()
      // return columnValue.indexOf(other) > -1
    }).show()
    //rows.filter(":contains('" + data + "')").show();
    //rows.filter(".depCode:contains('" + data + "')").show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="depCode">1</td>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="depCode">bar</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="depCode">2</td>
    <td>baz</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Using html() in `$(this).find('.depCode').html().indexOf(data)` would cause to search in the html markup. For text-only search you could use `$(this).find('.depCode').text().indexOf(data) >=0 `

Comment: I would also add something like `.toLowerCase()` to both the `data` and `.depCode` text, so searching for `"Bar"` will work.

Comment: @Mottie that's right indeed, thanks for the feedback :)